# Puzzled by exploit example?

Tags: c, security

I'm preparing for an interview and have been given this section of code by a friend who works there and says its good prep for some one of the question I will be asked about security. I don't know much about this side of things and am hoping to learn a bit so I can at least say something should I be asked.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

        FILE *inputFile;
        char filename[128];
        char strings[USHRT_MAX][40];
        unsigned short c = 0;

        strcpy(filename, argv[1]);
        inputFile = fopen (filename, "r");

        if (inputFile == NULL) {
            perror("Error: ");
            return(-1);
        }

        while (fscanf(inputFile, "%s", strings[c++] ) != EOF);
        fclose(inputFile);
    return(0);
    }
```

I know it has a vulnerability to do with being able to overflow the buffer as that is what he told me it was about, but beyond that I'm stuck. Can someone explain why this code is vulnerable?

Comment: `strcpy(filename, argv[1]);` oops.

Comment: `fscanf(inputFile, "%s", strings[c++])` oops. (which of the two overflows is worse depends on stack layout)

Comment: I think if you don't know how it can do that, you probablly aren't suitable for the job

Comment: @nneonneo  also the while part, every line could, also more than 40 lines will too :)

Comment: Wow, two buffer overflow vulnerabilities in one line of code. C can be amazing.

Comment: @DoxyLover  I wasn't talking about that one?  I was just saying the second one nneonneo pointed out has 2 if the while loop is included :)

Comment: a silly question : yes there is buffer overflow, it is possible to write on the stack after string[][] , but can it be really exploitable ? i mean we are in a main a return function won't be rewritten by such overflow, we can crash the program, but can we exploit it ?

Comment: @philippelhardy Well, firstly, in C this is undefined behaviour. How it works, whether it "works", etc, is undefined. Now that this has been explained, consider that the stack has been manipulated while *fscanf* is in control... What happens if fscanf happened to accidentally change it's caller to point back to the shell code, on the stack?

Comment: @modifiablelvalue you are deadly right, within fscanf we are bellow main stack then fscanf return value can be changed to point on exploit code. just a classical one.

Answer (score 4):

First, I recommend you read [this book](http://nostarch.com/hacking2.htm), which does a good job explaining how exploits work. It comes with a Linux VM and you can experiment with exploiting code. (FYI, I'm not affiliated with the book in any way, I just thought it was good.)

Second, I wanted to answer [philippe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1521926/philippe-lhardy)'s question in the comments: the return from `main()` is not the last thing that happens when a program executes. For example, you can step past the `return` from `main()` and see lots of interesting things happening:

```
Breakpoint 2, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fff5fbff320) at main.c:6
6       return 0;
(gdb) stepi
0x0000000100000f17  6       return 0;
(gdb)
0x0000000100000f1a  6       return 0;
(gdb)
0x0000000100000f1d  6       return 0;
(gdb)
0x0000000100000f20  6       return 0;
(gdb)
0x0000000100000f24  6       return 0;
(gdb)
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
0x0000000100000f25 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fff5fbff310) at main.c:6
6       return 0;
(gdb)
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
0x0000000100000ee4 in start ()
(gdb)
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
0x0000000100000ee6 in start ()
(gdb)
0x0000000100000f26 in dyld_stub_exit ()
(gdb)
0x0000000100000f44 in dyld_stub_puts ()
(gdb)
0x0000000100000f49 in dyld_stub_puts ()
(gdb)
0x0000000100000f34 in dyld_stub_puts ()
(gdb)
0x0000000100000f3b in dyld_stub_puts ()
(gdb)
0x0000000100000f3d in dyld_stub_puts ()
(gdb)
0x00007fff83b396a0 in dyld_stub_binder ()
(gdb)
0x00007fff83b396a1 in dyld_stub_binder ()
(gdb)
0x00007fff83b396a4 in dyld_stub_binder ()
(gdb)
0x00007fff83b396ab in dyld_stub_binder ()
(gdb)
0x00007fff83b396af in dyld_stub_binder ()
(gdb)
0x00007fff83b396b4 in dyld_stub_binder ()
(gdb)
0x00007fff83b396b9 in dyld_stub_binder ()
(gdb)
0x00007fff83b396be in dyld_stub_binder ()
(gdb)
0x00007fff83b396c3 in dyld_stub_binder ()
(gdb)
0x00007fff83b396c8 in dyld_stub_binder ()
(gdb)
```

... etc.

Comment: sorry i exhausted my +1 for today. this one enter in my categry 'it is better to ask a stupid question once and have a good answer than to never ask it and remain stupid for the rest of your life...'

Answer (score 0):

Always do bound check before playing with buffer.

```
#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 128    
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

        FILE *inputFile;
        char filename[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
        .
        .
        if(strlen(argv[1]) >= MAX_BUFFER_SIZE) // Bound check
        {
            /* Do something appropriate, such as throw an error. */
        }
        else {
        strcpy(filename, argv[1]);
        .
        .
}
```

[This](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/s-buffer-defend.html) might be helpful for your interview.